# Using Gatsby JS for a simple CRUD web app: is it recommendable?

Tags: reactjs, crud, gatsby

I'm looking into building a very simple CRUD web application fetching data from and sending data to a RESTful API backend.
Since I have a good experience with Gatsby JS and most of the features it ships are very useful, would you recommend using it instead of the more vanilla create-react-app? Are there any drawbacks that I should know of?

I've been searching the web for info and showcases but there's not much around on the topic of Gatsby JS used for web apps.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gatsby sites *are* web apps. Gatsby doesn't care what you do *with* that web app. In any case, requests for recommendations/etc. are off-topic on SO.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on requirements to your application. If you need static rendered pages, Gatsby JS is ok. If your application is not needed it, but you need any server side live rendering, maybe you should look on something like `nextjs`. If it doesn't require anything of that, using of Gatsby may be overwhelmed and unnecessary and `create-react-app` will be enough.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I actually need dynamic data to be displayed on the pages, since users will need to be able to create, update and delete items. I guess next.js or create-react-app would be best suited as you say.